# Dump of ColdFusion cache

Tags: cache, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-10

I am trying to give show a UI friendly dump of the cache status

```
<h1>Cache Status</h1>

<table class="tables dataTables">
<tr>
  <th>Cache</th>
  <th style="text-align : center;">Created Time</th>
  <th style="text-align : center;">Last Updated</th>
  <th style="text-align : center;">Last Hit</th>
  <th style="text-align : right;">Hit Count</th>
  <th style="text-align : right;">Hit Count %</th>
  <th style="text-align : right;">Size</th>
</tr>

<cfoutput>
  <cfloop index="cache" array="#cacheGetAllIds()#">
    <cfset metaData = cacheGetMetadata(cache)>
    <tr>
      <td>#cache#</td>
      <td style="text-align : center;">#LSTimeFormat(metadata.createdTime, "h:mm:ss")#</td>
      <td style="text-align : center;">#LSTimeFormat(metadata.lastHit, "h:mm:ss")#</td>
      <td style="text-align : center;">#LSTimeFormat(metadata.lastupdated, "h:mm:ss")#</td>
      <td style="text-align : right;">#metadata.hitcount#</td>
      <td style="text-align : right;"><cfset percent_of_hits = 100.0 * metadata.hitcount / metadata.cache_hitcount>
        #LSNumberFormat(percent_of_hits, '999.9')# %
      </td>
      <td style="text-align : right;">#LSNumberFormat(metadata.size)#</td>
    </tr>
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput> 
</table>
```

Bootstrap and Datatables formatting is applied. And it looks like this:

[image]

I want to make sure this is a good format and that I am not missing any easy to get at useful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the column definitions backwards.  On your header row you have:

Last Updated | Last Hit

but in the actual cf it looks like it's displaying in this order

Last Hit | Last Updated

Other than that it looks great!

Comment: I also found a divide by zero error.